# How to associate .i01 microstation file with ustation.exe in windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I want trying to associate file with the extension `.i01` with `microstation.exe` (ustation), but it is not in the default program list. I used default.exe file to reset the association of files, but that has not worked.

Comment: Did you try browsing for the program?

Answer (score 1):

Go to a file with extension .i01 right click Open with --> Choose Default Program --> Browse (button right down) ---> Broswe to microstation.exe and follow the rest of the steps and be sure to check the "Always use the selected program to open this kind of file"